# I removed date field, but still i am getting datetime_re.match(value) TypeError in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Model(added 'date_uploaded' field):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class VideoUploads(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.FileField(null=True)
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Videos'
```

I got the following Errors:

```
:
:
:
      File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1414, in get_prep_value
        value = super().get_prep_value(value)
      File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1274, in get_prep_value
        return self.to_python(value)
      File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1375, in to_python
        parsed = parse_datetime(value)
      File "C:\Users\adars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py", line 106, in parse_datetime
        match = datetime_re.match(value)
    TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Model (removed 'date_uploaded' field): but still getting the same error even after i removed 'date_uploaded' field

```
class VideoUploads(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.FileField(null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Videos'
```

How this migration works?

Comment: Remove the migration file that was failing (and the new one) and make new migrations.

Comment: thank you, its working